# Custom Logic and Proxy Classes in ADO.NET Data Services

Tags: ado.net, odata

I've just read "[Injecting Custom Logic in ADO.NET Data Services](http://weblogs.asp.net/cibrax/archive/2009/06/08/injecting-custom-logic-in-ado-net-data-services.aspx)" and my next question is, How do you get your `[WebGet]` method to show up in the client-side proxy classes? Sure, I can call this directly (RESTfully) with, say, `WebClient` but I thought the strong typing features in ADO.NET Data Services would "hide" this from me auto-magically.

So here we have:

```
public class MyService : DataService<MyDataSource>
{
    // This method is called only once to initialize service-wide policies.
    public static void InitializeService(IDataServiceConfiguration config)
    {
        config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("Customers", EntitySetRights.AllRead);
        config.SetServiceOperationAccessRule("CustomersInCity", ServiceOperationRights.All);
    }

    [WebGet]
    public IQueryable<MyDataSource.Customers> CustomersInCity(string city)
    {
        return from c in this.CurrentDataSource.Customers
               where c.City == city
               select c;
    } 

}
```

How can I get `CustomersInCity()` to show up in my client-side class defintions?

Comment: don't think you can with Odata, cause if I remember correctly the WSDL endpoint is disabled in this service.

Answer (score 1):

When you see your Odata in browser, you will see link ...
e.g. http://localhost:1234/odataService.svc

just write your method name after the link
for your method it will be something like this...

http://localhost:1234/odataService.svc/CustomersInCity?city="London"